# Spark createDataFrame is getting stuck (during spark-submit)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a spark dataframe from a list. The list has 1 or 2 elements So far I tried the 4 methods below, but strangely my application is getting stuck at spark.createDataFrame(). Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

**Update: These methods are working when tried in pyspark shell, but getting stuck during spark-submit**

Method 1

```
schema = StructType([
StructField('TABLE_NAME', StringType(), True)
])
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(table_name_list)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Method2

```
column = ["TABLE_NAME"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=table_name_list, schema = column)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Method3

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([table_name_list], StringType())
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Method 4

```
pd_df_tb_nm=pd.DataFrame({'TABLE_NAME':table_name_list})
print(pd_df_tb_nm) #printing pd df data
df_tb_nm=spark.createDataFrame(pd_df_tb_nm) 
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is coming only when I set master as YARN using config("spark.master", "yarn"). In local mode all of the above methods and the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70895854/13548763)  are working seamlessly)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple example of creating a dataframe from a single list
of strings

The following should work when calling the script using `spark-submit`.

```
from pyspark.sql import types

def main():

    arr = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "pear","grape"]
    arr = [[x] for x in arr] 

    arr_schema = (types.StructType([
            types.StructField('TABLE_NAME', types.StringType()),
            ]))

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=arr_schema)
    df.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example code').getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    main()
```

Comment: This and the methods I mentioned are working in pyspark shell, but when I use spark-submit it just stops executing at createDataFrame().

Comment: Any luck with the updated response?

Comment: Thank you, it works. The only difference between your code and mine is, you did not set config("spark.master", "yarn"). As soon as I change it to local or remove the config it works. I am new to this, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You would use the `config("spark.master", "yarn")` if you were using YARN. YARN is a resource manager that is often used in conjunction with HDFS (Hadoop). You can find some more info on that here --> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: I am running on a MapR hadoop cluster, and intentionally using Yarn. I will check that out once in a different environment and report. Thanks a lot @brendana for the fresh set of eye :)